# Git Bash on Windows - fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/scharko00/Documents/GitHub/myProject/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

Tags: git, github, branch, git-bash, github-desktop

I am having a weird problem with my git bash on windows, and i do not find any idea how to solve this.

I'm using Github Desktop and Visual Studio 2022 and do most of the git work in Github desktop. Now currently i had the problem that i need to remove a file from the repo using git rm file.txt --cached. So i open git bash and try to do this but git responses with:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/scharko00/Documents/GitHub/myProject/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

Pls pay attention to the "No such file or directory". There is a common problem that the .lock file gets stuck and git responses with "File exists" and there are a lot of solutions for this on the inet.

After some experiments (running git bash in elevated mode, create a dummy index.lock, switch to powershell, use git cmd,...) i found out that git gives me the same error on ALL commands.

So if i try to checkout a existing branch (or add a file or create a new branch), same error.

But i if i use Github Desktop, everything works just fine.

For me it seems like that git is missing some security settings but i just can't find out which.

Would be very thankful for any hint or idea.

[Screenshot Git Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvBuw.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

1. Git-Bash on Windows is (still) always **The Bad Idea (tm)**. You have to change your habits to using more native tools for your environment
2. I *suppose*, it's rather common problem of owner|permissions|ACLs and suggest to check this hypothesis|speculation

### Face

Find and document answers on these questions (step-by-step), even obvious:

1. Does `C:/Users/scharko00/Documents/GitHub/myProject/.git/` exist?
2. Who is the owner of `C:/Users/scharko00/Documents/GitHub/myProject/.git/` in the terms of local Windows-users and which permissions are defined for this subtree (folder properties - security - groups+permissions sections)?
3. Under which Windows-user is your Console running to execute git commands (Git inherits this user)? (!scharko00 || !Administrator Group) **have not permissions to write** in to `C:/Users/scharko00/Documents/` AFAICR

And anyway it's more for SU, than for SO, question IMNSHO